# Remove Letter After Number and Before Comma

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to remove any letters that occur after the first comma in a line

**some.file**

```
JAN,334X,333B,337A,338D,332Q,335H,331U
```

**Expected Result:**

```
JAN,334,333,337,338,332,335,331
```

**Code:**

```
sed -i 's/\[0-9][0-9][0-9].*,/[0-9][0-9][0-9],/g' some.file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$ sed 's/,\([0-9]*\)[^,]*/,\1/g' <<<'JAN,334X,333B,337A,338D,332Q,335H,331U'
JAN,334,333,337,338,332,335,331
```

You need to capture the digits with round parenthesis in order to use the captured string in the replacement. The option `g` does this for every occurrence.

**Comparison of the different answers**

Test data:

```
$ > data; for ((x=1000000;x>0;x--)); do echo 'JAN,334X,333B,337A,338D,332Q,335H,331U' >> data; done
```

My answer is the slowest:

```
$ time sed 's/,\([0-9]*\)[^,]*/,\1/g' < data >/dev/null

real    0m16.368s
user    0m16.296s
sys     0m0.024s
```

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233152/402322) is a bit faster:

```
$ time sed ':;s/[A-Z],/,/2;t;s/[A-Z]$//' < data >/dev/null

real    0m9.669s
user    0m9.624s
sys     0m0.012s
```

But [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233360/402322) is the fastet:

```
$ time sed 's/[A-Z]//4g' < data >/dev/null

real    0m4.905s
user    0m4.856s
sys     0m0.028s
```

Comment: Can not find this in the question.

Comment: No he says remove letters after coma.

Comment: he actually says after the _first_ comma :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks everyone for steering me in the right direction and pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a small loop (this is GNU `sed`);

```
sed ':;s/[A-Z],/,/2;t;s/[A-Z]$//'
```

It only deletes the second letter preceding a comma, and loops. Finally, it deletes the letter at the line's end, if there is one.

Comment: that is truly marvellous

Comment: Notable: this version is about 50% faster than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues are:

- No need to escape `[`.
- Your `replace` value is wrong. Ex: `s/regex/replace/g`

Use this:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)[a-zA-Z],/\1,/g' -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)[a-zA-Z]$/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You should omit the `*` and the first `\` looks like a mistake i.e.

```
sed -i 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9].,/[0-9][0-9][0-9],/g' some.file
```

but I think you also want to capture the number ...

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\).,/\1,/g' some.file
```

Would be helpful if you posted your **actual output** as well ...

Answer (score 2):

Since question is tagged `linux`, this `GNU sed` option comes in handy

```
$ echo 'JAN,334X,333B,337A,338D,332Q,335H,331U' | sed -E 's/[A-Z](,|$)/\1/2g'
JAN,334,333,337,338,332,335,331
```

- `2g` means replace from 2nd match onwards till end of line

If number of letters is known for first column, this can be simplified to

```
$ echo 'JAN,334X,333B,337A,338D,332Q,335H,331U' | sed 's/[A-Z]//4g'
JAN,334,333,337,338,332,335,331
```

Comment: This is the fastest. About three times faster than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need for sed, coreutils will do:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1 data) <(cut -d, -f2- data | tr -d 'A-Z')
```

This takes **.3 seconds** on my computer when run on the data file generated in [*ceving's*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232958/1331399) answer.

Comment: +++ this approach is certainly pretty fast.. equivalent `perl -F'/,/,$_,2' -ne '$F[1]=~tr/A-Z//d; print "$F[0],$F[1]"'` takes about `0m0.885s` compared to `0m0.332s` for the paste+cut+tr combo

Comment: @Sundeep: Impressive.  How does `/,/,$_,2` get interpreted?  I cannot find that syntax documented in `perlrun(1)`.

Comment: same syntax as http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html , result saved to `@F` array...